# Mobile site link to youtube video, close app after video finished?

Tags: mobile, iphone

I'm linking to Youtube videos on my mobile site.
On iPhone, when you click on a youtube link, it begins playing using the Youtube App
When the video is finished, the Youtube App is still open--you have to close it and reopen the browser to get back to where you were.

Is there a way to make it go back to the browser when it is finished playing?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the iphone cannot use the standard FLASH player, therefore it defaults to the youtube app on your iphone. At that point the application wont know to go back to your site.  Another option is to embed videos in your site using the HTML 5 standard.

Last i checked youtube was iteself doing an limited HTML5 trial on their site as they try to move away from the flash player.  I think you can try to embed one of their videos in HTML5 format.